# python Flask redirect(url_for()) not working

Tags: flask

i'm making a sign up page in flask but when i press submit it doesn't redirect to the home page

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request == 'POST':
        input1 = request.form.get("input1")
        input2 = request.form.get("input2")
        
        return redirect(url_for("home"))
    
    return render_template('lo.html')

@app.route('/home', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def home():

    return render_template('ho.html')



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

i have no idea why it doesn't work can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you visit the “/“ path in browser? That’s “GET” method, not match your “POST” method. In addition, you should use `if request.method == 'POST':`  to check the request method in flask.

Try to remove the condition, it may work as you expected.